# Programmatically changing theme after hook_custom_theme

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to change the theme in code in drupal7.  hook_custom_theme is too early since I need spaces_init to have happened already.  The themekey module uses custom_theme so that's out.

The only method I've found so far is to change the theme callback using menu_alter.  What other options are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `hook_custom_theme()` and `hook_init()` are invoked from [_drupal_bootstrap_full()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_full/7), which contains the following code.

```
menu_set_custom_theme();   // It invokes hook_custom_theme(). 
drupal_theme_initialize();
module_invoke_all('init');
```

The reason of the order is explained in the comment before that code, which says:

> Prior to invoking `hook_init()`, initialize the theme (potentially a custom one for this page), so that:
>
> - Modules with `hook_init()` implementations that call `theme()` or `theme_get_registry()` don't initialize the incorrect theme.
> - The theme can have `hook_*_alter()` implementations affect page building (e.g., `hook_form_alter()`, `hook_node_view_alter()`, `hook_page_alter()`), ahead of when rendering starts.

It seems that your situation is a circular-reference situation, where an implementation of `hook_custom_theme()` depends from `hook_init()`, and an implementation of `hook_init()` could depend from the value returned from `hook_custom_theme()`.

If you are sure that the result of `hook_custom_theme()` doesn't influence the code of `spaces_init()`, which doesn't need the theme to be initialized, then you could invoke `spaces_init()` in your `hook_custom_theme()` using `module_invoke('spaces', 'init')`, but that sounds like a hack, and subject of problems if `spaces_init()` is changed, and it actually needs a theme to be initialized before being executed.

Comment: So far so good on running spaces_init early (although I had to do purl_init instead since spaces didn't work without purl).  Still testing though and I won't be surprised if something is a little off.

Comment: Went with this one.  Also added a hook_module_implements_alter to prevent spaces from running init again.

Answer (score 2):

Implementations of [`hook_custom_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7) are only [invoked](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/invokes/hook_custom_theme/7) from [`menu_get_custom_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_custom_theme/7). The `theme callback` set for the current menu item is invoked right after the `hook_custom_theme()` implementations. So if your `hook_custom_theme()` implementation is invoked too early, the `theme callback` for your page will also be invoked too early.

These seems to be the only safe ways to change the theme used on the page.

Having `drupal_theme_initialize` (which is what invoke `menu_get_custom_theme()`) invoked before implementation of `hook_init()` (such as `spaces_init()`) doesn't seems right. The theme should not be initialized so early. Unless a theme initializing function (such as `theme()`) is invoked in an `hook_init()` or `hook_boot()` implementation.

I would check if any of the `hook_init()` on your site initialize the theme. If one does, try changing the modules' weight or [`hook_modules_implements_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to ensure `spaces_init()` is invoked before. This should allow your `hook_custom_theme()` implementation to rely on `spaces_init()`.

Comment: In common.inc drupal_theme_initialize() is run immediately before module_invoke_all('init').  I don't think I can delay hook_custom_theme till after init without modifying core.  To clarify, I don't mind setting the theme earlier, I just need to have spaces initialized.  Running purl_init during my custom_theme hook is working so far.  Still looking for problems with that approach though.

Comment: Right, I missed the call to `drupal_theme_initialize()` in `_drupal_bootstrap_full()`. Try kiamlaluno's and invoke `spaces_init()` from your `hook_custom_theme()`.